# Change LazyQueryContainer.addContainerProperty behaviour when adding strings

Tags: java, vaadin

when we use method

```
LazyQueryContainer#addContainerProperty
```

like that

```
container.addContainerProperty(name, String.class, null, true, true);
```

we will get field which will be a plain text field.

when we use it like that:

```
container.addContainerProperty(name, SomeEnum.class, null, true, true);
```

we will get field which ListSelect to filter

how can I do this for String.class?

Comment: I'm not a Vaadin user but I assume one of the problems is that `SomeEnum.class` makes it easy to grab the potential values and display a list while `String.class` would allow _any_ input and hence only a text field is used. You might have to provide a list of elements to chose from, maybe there's some support for enumerables/collections/arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ListSelect as the container property type directly:

```
container.addContainerProperty(name, ListSelect.class, null, true, true);
```

And then create a separate ListSelect instance for each item (do not try to reuse the same instance for all rows!) and set the property e.g. like this:

```
item.getItemProperty(name).setValue(listSelect);
```

See also documentation about components inside a Table: https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-table/#components.table.features.components

For Grid you might be interested in SimpleSelectRenderer within the Grid Renderers collection add-on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/grid-renderers-collection-for-vaadin7 or maybe even ComponentRenderer add-on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/componentrenderer (but note that for big Grids there can be a notable performance hit)